# What would be the correct way to convert a column's text into multiple columns?

Tags: excel

I have a column called Message that contains this info.

```
    CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5
```

I would like to split this into columns with

```
[Column] CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
[Column] Request for API:  /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment
[Column] Caller: C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 
[Column] CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
[Column] RequestedSchemas:    {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy,   {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}
[Column] TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5
```

I am aware of the Text-to-columns function in Excel but I do not believe that I am using it correctly because it does not split them into those categories.

Comment: Do the *cells' data* include return carriages, just like in your top example?

Comment: @gravity I do not believe so I had to add the spaces when I put that in here. I can post the unformatted data. I edited the top example to demonstrate what it really looks like in Excel

Comment: Will the result always have the same 6 columns?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way with formulas:

1. Put the categories of each column (CorrelationId:, Request for API:) in cells `B1:G1`
2. in `B2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =LEFT($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2)-1)
   ```
3. in `C2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =MID($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2),FIND(D$1,$A2,FIND(C$1,$A2))-FIND(C$1,$A2))
   ```
4. in `D2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =MID($A2,FIND(D$1,$A2),FIND(E$1,$A2,FIND(D$1,$A2))-FIND(D$1,$A2))
   ```
5. in `E2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =MID($A2,FIND(E$1,$A2),FIND(F$1,$A2,FIND(E$1,$A2))-FIND(E$1,$A2,FIND(D$1,$A2)))
   ```
6. in `F2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =MID($A2,FIND(F$1,$A2),FIND(G$1,$A2,FIND(F$1,$A2))-FIND(F$1,$A2))
   ```
7. in `G2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(G$1,$A2)+1)
   ```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution that has helped me separate it out much easier thank you to both you and @gravity

Answer (score 1):

Choose the data selection area that you want to split on return carriages.

1. Highlight the cells you want to split.

2. Go to `Data` and then `Text to Columns`

3. Choose `Delimited` and then hit `Next`

4. Unselect `Tab` and select `Other` instead.  In the `Other` box, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

If your original data is properly split, you should see the data get dumped into separate columns now.

PS - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in the `Other` box tells Excel to look for a "Line Break."  Assuming your data is just like described, and universally formatted as such, this should work across the board for you.